# how to store ldap data in ruby on rails application database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise, ldap

i have created a web app with rails4 and authentication system is developed with devise_ldap_authenticable gem.
where i am using username for login not email. but i want to store email in my users table.
My user model is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
#@attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
# not required for LDAP :recoverable, :registerable, :validatable
devise :ldap_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable

validates_uniqueness_of :email, :allow_blank => true

 before_save :get_ldap_email

 def get_ldap_email
  self.email = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username, "mail")
 end
end
```

But in users table of email field its storing data like

```
`email` = '--- !ruby/array:Net::BER::BerIdentifiedArray\ninternal:\n- !ruby/string:Net::BER::BerIdentifiedString\n str: !binary |-\n cy5naG9zaEBzYW1zdW5nLmNvbQ==\n ber_identifier: 4\nivars:\n :@ber_identifier: 49\n'
```

My log says
    LDAP: Requested param mail has value ["s.ghosh@example.com"]

How i will store this value to my users table. where im doing wrong? please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add the following then its totally ok

```
def get_ldap_email
  self.email = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username, "mail").first
end
```